# win32com.client Python - Excel task remains running after telling application to quit

Tags: excel, python-3.7, exit

I've seen a couple questions similar to this, but they both appear to involve VBA and not Python.

This is a relatively recent error, so I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using Python 3.7 now.

Basically, using the Dispatch method from win32com.client, I am able to open a new Excel workbook and make my edits as I always have been. However, for some reason, I am unable to tell the application to quit successfully.

Used to be that I could write:
`self.excel_app.Quit()`

But now, I'm getting an AttributeError, of all things. Saying the Excel.Application does not have a Quit() attribute. Again, this is Python 3.7. What happened?

[EDIT]
Relevant code:

```
import sys
from win32com.client import Dispatch
#...
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        self.excel_app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        self.report_workbook = self.excel_app.Workbooks.Add()
        #...
    
    def close_excel(self):
        try:
            self.excel_app.Quit()
        except Exception as ex:
            sys.stdout.write("Could not quit application.\n-> ({}) {}\n".format(ex.__class__.__name__, ex))
        self.excel_app = None
```

The exception printed to the terminal is:

```
Could not quit application.
(AttributeError) Excel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: You're asking us to explain why code we cannot see isn't working as you'd expect, which is unreasonable. Please provide the relevant code in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my error was coming from the fact that I was still using threading.Thread as the base class for the object trying to do this. Apparently it doesn't work so well with the Dispatch Excel objects anymore, and I'm trying to move away from Threads anyway.